# Proof verification in second order logic

Tags: logic, proof-theory, incompleteness

There cannot exist an algorithm to verify a proof in second-order logic, because there is no finitary, complete, and sound set of inference rules. So how exactly do we get results in and about second-order logic?

That is, if a mathematician proves that ZFC with second-order logic implies X in some model, how can I tell whether the proof is correct or makes unjustified leaps?

In addition, if the answer is simply that we use some fixed finitary and sound set of inference rules, but not a complete set, isn't that just equivalent to first order ZFC + some finite collection of axioms, so really we are just proving first order theorems about systems with more axioms than ZFC?

Comment: Just because there is no algorithm doesn't mean we cannot verify by hand proofs. There is just no uniform way of verifying *all* the proofs.

Comment: If there is no finite set of rules that can verify an arbitrary proof, what does it mean to verify by hand? Just look at it and see if it "makes sense"?

Comment: @JakobEriksson Did you ever find the answer to your question? I think Asaf is saying that you can verify any particular proof, where the inference rules are stated... but not all of them in a general way.